# Determinant of ADM metric

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, linear-algebra, adm-formalism

I am studying inflation and for the calculation of the bispectrum we are using the ADM formalism where the metric is the following form:

$$g_{\mu\nu}=\begin{bmatrix}-N^2+N^iN_i&N_i\\N_i&h_{ij}\end{bmatrix}.$$

It is then given that the determinant of the metric is given by $-N^2h$ but I don't know how to find this using the metric. According to a paper that i read, one can obtain the determinant by using Cramer's rule on the $g^{00}$ component. But I am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Could you please put a link to the paper you are reading?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$\begin{bmatrix}-N^2+{\bf N}^t\mathbb{h} {\bf N}&{\bf N}^t \mathbb{h}\cr \mathbb{h}{\bf N}&\mathbb{h}\end{bmatrix}
~=~\begin{bmatrix}1 &{\bf N}^t \cr {\bf 0}&\mathbb{1}\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}-N^2 &{\bf 0}^t \cr {\bf 0}&\mathbb{h}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1 &{\bf 0}^t \cr {\bf N}&\mathbb{1}\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: Yes, then the answer is expected since the determinant is just the product of the determinant of the three matrices. What is the general procedure that you used to "diagonalise" the metric into the three matrices? Qmechanic♦

Comment: The general procedure is [Gaussian elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination) for symmetric matrices.

Answer (score 0):

Some useful quantities borrowed from ADM formalism that will be useful here are

$$N^i = h^{ij}N_j$$
$$N_i \equiv {}^4g_{0i}$$
$$    {}^4g^{0i} = N^i/N^2,$$

where ${}^4g^{ij}$ is the four-metric and $h_{ij}$ as you have used is the three-metric.
And finally don't forget, $det(g_{ij})=g$. These are relations are very much enough to get the desired value. For more detailed information refer to

http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Arnowitt-Deser-Misner_formalism